# Setting a button on Gridview row, conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a button on my Gridview:

```
<asp:Button ID="lnk_ship" runat="server" CssClass="btn-mini" Text="Ship Software" />
```

I am loading my Gridview from SQL, to a Class, then a DataBind() event,

```
protected void FilterResults(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var shipments = new List<SoftShipments>();
            DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox1.Text);
            DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(Textbox2.Text);
            string cvt1 = "'" + dt1.Year.ToString() + "-" + dt1.Month.ToString() + "-" + dt1.Day.ToString() + "'";
            string cvt2 = "'" + dt2.Year.ToString() + "-" + dt2.Month.ToString() + "-" + dt2.Day.ToString() + "'";
            string qry = null;
            if (Showshipped.Checked)
            {
                qry = "select * from sft_Ship where sft_Entry_Dt between " + cvt1 + " and " + cvt2;
            }
            else {
                qry = "select * from sft_Ship where sft_Entry_Dt between " + cvt1 + " and " + cvt2 + " and sft_shipped = 'No'";
            }

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString("softship"));
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

                shipments.Add(new SoftShipments() { index = (int) dr["id"], softtitle = dr["sft_SoftTitle"].ToString(), 
                    productID = dr["sft_ProductID"].ToString(), ver = dr["sft_Version"].ToString(), 
                    custnam = dr["sft_CustName"].ToString(), title = dr["sft_Title"].ToString(), 
                    comp = dr["sft_Company"].ToString(), shipAddr = dr["sft_ShipAddress"].ToString(),
                    dept = dr["sft_Dept"].ToString(), city = dr["sft_City"].ToString(), state = dr["sft_State"]
                    .ToString(), postalCd = dr["sft_PostalCd"].ToString(), country = dr["sft_Country"].ToString(),
                    email = dr["sft_Email"].ToString(), entry_date = dr["sft_Entry_Dt"].ToString(), 
                    ship_date = dr["sft_Ship_Dt"].ToString(), shipped = dr["sft_Shipped"].ToString()
                    });
            }



            gdv_Ship.DataSource = shipments;
            gdv_Ship.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

I would like to load the Gridview with the button visible if the value "shipped = 'No' or not visible if 'Yes' ... just not quite certain where to add this code? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the `databound` event of the grid, and then show/hide the buttons in the template with a `FindControl("controlName")`